# Mean, modus and median per group

Tags: python

I have a dataset df with valuations of several names of hospitals (df[Hospital]) like below (just a short part of it, in total 6500 rows):

[image]

In the end I have a list of number of valuations per hospital like below:

[image]

What I need to know in the end is the MEAN, MODUS and MEDIAN of the total group of hospitals. In this case the MEAN is 2167, the MODUS is 3000 and the MEDIAN is 2500. But how should the script look like? I know how to calculate this for the total column (df['Hospital'].mean()), but how do I do this with calculating a mean per hospital first?

Comment: Try grouping the rows by hospital and calculating your statistics on those groups (assuming you are using Pandas): https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using **Group By** & **Agg** as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Hospital":['A','A','A','B','B','C','C'],
              "value":[1,1,2,100,200,20,2]})
              
 df.groupby('Hospital').agg(Mean_value=('value','mean'),
                                    Median_value=('value','median'),
                                    Modus_value=('value',lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
                                    ).reset_index()
```

[image]

As OP asked for total Mean, Median & Mode in comments, adding code for the same:

You can break below code in two dataframes from where **## Total Calculation start here** is mentioned in the code.

```
df.groupby('Hospital').agg(Mean_value=('value','mean'),
                                    Median_value=('value','median'),
                                    Modus_value=('value',lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
                                    ).reset_index()[['Mean_value','Median_value','Modus_value']].\ ## Total Calculation start here
                                    assign(grp_col = '1').\
                                    groupby('grp_col').\
                                    agg(Mean_value=('Mean_value','mean'),
                                    Median_value=('Median_value','median'),
                                    Modus_value=('Modus_value',lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
                                    ).reset_index()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: And my next step is getting a total mean, median and modus, so Mean of hospital A, B and C is 54,1, Median is 11,0 and Modus is 100. That should be the end result. How do I get that result at once?

Comment: Do you need total Mean, Median & Mode of all the individual hospital's Mean, Median & Mode that is getting calculated above? Like a single row with three columns?

Comment: yes, that is my goal